# LibGDX setup project network timeout

Tags: android, libgdx, project-setup

I am new in LibGDX development. I try to create LibGDX project using `libGDX- project-setup.jar`. But I always got an network error:

> Downloading
>   http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)...

Even if I installed Gradle-2.4 and set GRADLE_HOME environment, but everytime when I create libGDX project, it's required download the gradle-2.4.zip and always thrown an above error. So, my questions are:

1. Why always need to download gradle?
2. Does the error affect to my project setup?
3. How to stop download gradle? Because it had been installed.

Thanks !